# Trouble installing and importing pyHook

Tags: python, pip, pyhook

This is my first question on this site so I hope I format this correctly. I also am very new to programming so bear with my lack of knowledge, thank you!

I'm trying to install pyHook like so and I keep getting this error message:

```
C:\Python27>py -2.7 -m pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-cp27M-win_amd64.whl
pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-cp27M-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I have python 2.7.14 as you can see from below:

```
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit 
(AMD64)] on win32
```

Just in case, I tried updating pip and It said it was up to date. I also tried install this version of the .whl and I get the same error:

```
C:\Python27>py -2.7 -m pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

From reading online I believe cp27 indicates its for python 2.7 and to be safe I tried the 64 bit and 32 bit files, but nothing seems to work. If anyone could offer up any solutions or advice, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your pip's version? `py -2.7 -m pip --version`

Comment: `pip 9.0.1 from c:\python27\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)` is what comes up

Comment: I'm having the same problem. so please, someone give an answer.

Comment: Are you on 32 or 64 bit OS? Also what OS are you on, Linux, Mac, or Windows variant

Comment: 64 bit Windows 10

Comment: @Br0therBrigham what do `py -2.7 -c "import pip; print(pip.pep425tags.get_platform())"` and `py -2.7 -c "import pip; print(pip.pep425tags.get_abi_tag())"` return? Also, what wheels do you use for installing? I don't see any wheels for `pyHook` uploaded on PyPI.

Comment: @hoefling the first one returned "win32" and the second one returned "cp27m". and I'm new to python and I don't really know what Wheels are.

Comment: @Br0therBrigham so you need a `cp27-cp27m-win32` wheel. Run `py -2.7 -m pip install https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/u2yrk7ps/pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl`, do you get a clean install?

Comment: @hoefling I get a Client error.

Comment: @Br0therBrigham what client error? can you elaborate? Please post the  complete error trace.

Comment: @hoefling the error trace is too long for a comment. but this is the first half. HTTP error 404 while getting https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/u2yrk7ps/pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
  Could not install requirement pyHook==1.5.1 from https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/u2yrk7ps/pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl because of error 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/u2yrk7ps/pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl

Comment: Hmm, indeed the website is also not available for me. I uploaded the files to a mirror on Github, try this one out: `py -2.7 -m pip install https://github.com/hoefling/pyhook-wheels/raw/master/pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl`.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Python 2.7, then pyHook and was able to get it working following these exact steps.

Note, I was using Anaconda to create the Python 2.7 environment and Windows 10 is my OS.

1. `conda create -n python27 python=2.7`  This created a new conda environment with python 2.7.14.
2. `activate python27`
3. `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`  This installed pip version 10.0.0
4. Downloaded pyHook from the [unofficial windows binaries](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook).

   - Specifically: pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
5. Navigated to downloads folder in command prompt
6. `pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`

That installed it properly with no error messages. Hope that helps. My guess is that the new pip version fixes it, or there is a problem with how you are installing Python 2.7, so try Anaconda (or miniconda if you want to keep it light)

I was also able to import it with no problem after these steps.

Comment: I have installed other libraries such as Pillow. so I don't think it has anything to do with pythons installation. pip is also updated to the newest version.

Comment: Considering I was able to get it to work on my machine following those exact steps it could be worth a try, starting with using a conda environment.

Answer (score -1):

> Many binaries depend on numpy-1.13+mkl and the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 (x64, x86, and SP1 for CPython 2.7), Visual C++ 2010 (x64, x86, for CPython 3.4), or the Visual C++ 2017 (x64 or x86 for CPython 3.5, 3.6, and 3.7) redistributable packages.
>
> Install numpy+mkl before other packages that depend on it.

I have Microsoft Visual C++ 2008.I just do this,

```
python -m pip install numpy-1.13.3+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

`python -m pip install pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`

then it work.

Comment: Wheels with precompiled extensions don't need any compilers to be installed. That's the reason why they exist in the first place. Also, `pyHook` doesn't depend on `numpy`, so this answer is completely wrong.

Comment: @hoefling There are some hack in numpy which will deal with 32bit and 64bit incompatibility.